# Catching Complete action using

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hey, How can I get my application into the Complete action using for Long press of the Search button? I already know that the action is SEARCH_LONG_PRESS, but what do I do with this in the Manifest so that my application will show up in this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting a category in the intent filter like this?

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you shared the exact modifications you used (substitute com.example.project for your app name if necessary) as a comment or another answer. That way this page can be useful for more than just you.